# Swift title change color of attributed string remains default blue color

Tags: swift

Checked many topics here, but cannot find solution to make it work.

Button with attributed text not changing its text color.

Final version of code:

```
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.center

let forgotCodeAttributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "forgot_code_2_lines".localized(),
                                                       attributes: [ kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName as NSAttributedString.Key: style])

forgotCodeAttributedTitle.addAttribute(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName as NSAttributedStringKey, value: Colors.BTN_FORGOT_CODE_TEXT_COLOR, range: NSMakeRange(0, forgotCodeAttributedTitle.string.count))

btnForgotCode.setAttributedTitle(forgotCodeAttributedTitle, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the `NSMutableAttributedString` `attributes` parameter:

```
attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style]
```

and change your `addAttribute code to this:

```
let forgotCodeAttributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "forgot_code_2_lines", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style])
```

Or, even simpler, use this code to set paragraph styling and foreground color in a single statement:

```
let forgotCodeAttributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "forgot_code_2_lines", attributes: 
    [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: style, 
     NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

Comment: Thanks, second option worked. However, i changed tint color in storyboard and got same effect. But will use code version